# Why regexp_replace oracle query is replacing ALL the numbers with the same number?

Tags: oracle

I need to return an address string, which is in Hebrew And the original column has the numbers reversed - which means 12 is represented as 21 etc.
But -The problem is that if I have 2 numbers in the address line - let say Street number and floor number,
my query replaces both numbers with the same number.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('Rachel Street 27, Floor 42' , '(\d+)', 
REVERSE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Rachel Street 27, Floor 42', '\d+'))) as reversed from dual;
```

Results in

`Rachel Street 72, Floor 72`

My desired result is

`Rachel Street 27, Floor 24`

Comment: regex_replace has additional parameters to specify from which position, which occurrence, ... you should read the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use nested replaces.

Sample data, presuming there are at most 2 numeric values in address:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Rachel Street 27, Floor 42'   from dual union all
  3     select 'High Avenue 73, Apartment A' from dual),
```

For simplicity, I'm extracting numbers first (no problem in having it all in a single query, but it makes expressions more complex)

```
  4  temp as
  5    -- 1st and 2nd numeric value
  6    (select col, regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1) dig1, regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) dig2
  7     from test
  8    )
```

Finally, perform replaces:

```
  9  -- nested replaces
 10  select col,
 11    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '\d+', reverse(dig1), 1, 1),
 12                                       '\d+', reverse(dig2), 1, 2) result
 13  from temp;

COL                         RESULT
--------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Rachel Street 27, Floor 42  Rachel Street 72, Floor 24
High Avenue 73, Apartment A High Avenue 37, Apartment A

SQL>
```

---

Although this isn't an issue here, note that `reverse` is undocumented function and you should probably NOT use it.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that none of your numbers are going to have more than 9 digits then you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         address,
         '(\d)(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?',
         '\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1'
       ) AS reversed
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (address) AS
SELECT 'Rachel Street 27, Floor 42' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ Street 123456789, Floor 987654321' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| REVERSED |
| --- |
| Rachel Street 72, Floor 24 |
| XYZ Street 987654321, Floor 123456789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oX9571ID)

---

> Why `regexp_replace` oracle query is replacing ALL the numbers with the same number?

Because the default for `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is to match the first occurrence of the pattern so you are asking `REGEXP_REPLACE` to match all digit strings and replace them with the reverse of the first digit string.